# angularjs binding a model to whats inside the model?

Tags: angularjs

If anyone has a better suggestion for the wording of my question please edit.

I have this case :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="panels[ <whats inside the input> ]"/>
```

I want to have this model bind to the panels array where the position of the array is determined by what someone types in the input.

example:

if someone types 3 into the input I want ng-model to be panels[2] , is there a way of doing this ?

Comment: I don't think it will work this way, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing what `ng-model` does.  `ng-model` is what the input binds to.  So, whatever you type would go into the field defined by `ng-model`.  By assigning `ng-model` to an index based on what is typed, you are essentially asking for `ng-model` to bind to two different things.

Here is a take on what you are asking.  You can just index your value by a variable bound to a second input:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input ng-model="index" />
  <input ng-model="panels[index]" />
  {{panels}}
</div>
```

The JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.panels = [ "one", "two", "three" ];
}
```